# display selected item from firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, selecteditem

i'm working on a rental Car project,

```js
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar >
    <ion-title>Nos Voitures</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
 <ion-card>
  <img src="assets/audi.png"/>
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-card-title>
      Toyota prado
      </ion-card-title>
      <p> Catégorie :suv/4*4 <br>
          Energie : Diesel <br>
          Puissance fiscale:8cv <br></p>
    <button ion-button block outline color="gmail" (click)="detail1('assets/audi.png','Toyota Prado','suv/4*4','diesel','8 cv','5 personnes','5 portes','Manuel','4 airbags','99€','93€','89€','80€','75€','70€')">Détails</button>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card> 
 <ion-card>
  <img src="assets/accent.png"/>
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-card-title>
      hyundai accent
      </ion-card-title>
    <p> Catégorie :citadine <br>
          Energie : Diesel <br>
          Puissance fiscale:7cv <br></p>
<button ion-button block outline color="gmail" (click)="detail2('assets/accent.png','Hyundai accent','citadine','diesel','7 cv','5 personnes','5 portes','Manuel','4 airbags','99€','93€','89€','80€','75€','70€')">Détails</button>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

```js
export class CarPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public cardata:Cardata) {
    
  }
detail1(p,m,ca,e,pu,pe,po,b,a,c,pr1,pr2,pr3,pr4,pr5,pr6){
   this.navCtrl.push(DetailAudiPage,{
     Photo:p,
     Marque:m,
     Categorie:ca,
     Energie :e,
     Puissance :pu,
     Personne :pe,
     Portes :po,
     Boite :b,
     Airbags:a,
    Prix:pr1,
    Prix2:pr2,
    Prix3:pr3,
    Prix4:pr4,
    Prix5:pr5,
    Prix6:pr6
   });
 }


 detail2(p,m,ca,e,pu,pe,po,b,a,pr1,pr2,pr3,pr4,pr5,pr6){
   this.navCtrl.push(DetailAudiPage,{
     Photo:p,
     Marque:m,
     Categorie:ca,
     Energie :e,
     Puissance :pu,
     Personne :pe,
     Portes :po,
     Boite :b,
    Airbags:a,
    Prix:pr1,
    Prix2:pr2,
    prix3:pr3,
    prix4:pr4,
    prix5:pr5,
    prix6:pr6
   });
 }
}
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';

import { ReservationPage } from '../reservation/reservation';

@Component({
  selector: 'detail',
  templateUrl: 'detail.html'
})
export class DetailPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public navparams:NavParams ) {
  } 
   marque = this.navparams.get("Marque");
   photo = this.navparams.get("Photo");
   categorie=this.navparams.get("Categorie");
   energie = this.navparams.get("Energie");
   puissance = this.navparams.get("Puissance");
   personne = this.navparams.get("Personne");
   portes = this.navparams.get("Portes");
   boite = this.navparams.get("Boite");
   airbag =this.navparams.get("Airbags"); 
   prix=this.navparams.get('Prix1');
   prix2=this.navparams.get('Prix2');
   prix3=this.navparams.get('Prix3');
   prix4=this.navparams.get('Prix4');
   prix5=this.navparams.get('Prix5');
   prix6=this.navparams.get('Prix6');
reservercmd(){
   this.navCtrl.push(ReservationPage);
 }
}
```

```js
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar >
    <ion-title ><div text-center>{{marque}}</div></ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
 <ion-card>
  <img src="{{photo}}"/>
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-card-title>
      {{marque}}
      </ion-card-title>
     </ion-card-content>
</ion-card> 

<ion-card>
  <ion-card-header> <div text-capitalize>Fiche technique </div></ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content id="marque">
    <p> Marque : {{marque}} <br>
       Catégorie :{{categorie}}<br>
      Energie : {{energie}} <br>
      Puissance fiscale:{{puissance}} <br>
      Nombre de personnes : {{personne}}<br>
      Nombre de portes :{{portes}} <br>
      Boite à vitesse : {{boite}}<br>
      Airbags: {{airbag}} <br>
      </p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>

<ion-card>
     <ion-card-header> Tarif</ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    <h1><b>Tarif normal(Juil-Août) </b></h1>
    <p> 1 à 3 jours:{{prix}}/jour <br>
        4 à 10 jours:{{prix2}}/jour  <br>
        Plus de 11 jours:{{prix3}} /jour
    </p>
    <h1><b> Tarif promotionnel </b></h1>
     <p> 1 à 3 jours:{{prix4}}/jour <br>
        4 à 10 jours:{{prix5}}/jour  <br>
        Plus de 11 jours:{{prix6}}/jour 
    </p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
<ion-card>
     <ion-card-header> Nos avantages</ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    <p> Assurance tous risques<br>
     Une large gamme de véhicules<br>
     Kilométrage illimité<br>
     Livraison gratuit : Aéroport, Hôtel, Riad <br>
     Siège bébé 2€ <br>
      Conducteur additionnel 2€ <br>
      GPS 2€<p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
    <button ion-button block outline color="gmail" (click)="reservercmd()">Réserver</button>
</ion-content>
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
/*
  Generated class for the Cardata provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class Cardata {
public cardetails:any;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    var fireref=firebase.database().ref('voiture'); 
  this.cardetails=firebase.database().ref('voiture').child('toyota');
  var accent=fireref.child('accent');
  var peugeot=fireref.child('peugeot');
  var renault=fireref.child('renault');
  var ford=fireref.child('ford');
  var dacia=fireref.child('dacia');
  var i10=fireref.child('i10');
  var nissan=fireref.child('nissan');
  var Mitsubishi=fireref.child('mitsubishi');

  
     var data1={
       marque:"Toyota Prado",
        photo:"assets/audi.png",
        categorie:'suv/4*4',
        energie:'diesel',
        carburant:'8 cv',
        nbr_personne:'5 personnes',
        nbr_portes:'5 portes',
        airbags:'oui',
        prix:'1000 dh'}
     var data2={
       marque:"Hyundai Accent",
        photo:"assets/accent.png",
        categorie:'citadine',
        energie:'diesel',
        carburant:'8 cv',
        nbr_personne:'5 personnes',
        nbr_portes:'5 portes',
        airbags:'oui',
        prix:'1000 dh'
     } 
     var data3={
       marque:"Peugeot 301",
        photo:"assets/peugeot.jpg",
        categorie:'citadine',
        energie:'diesel',
        carburant:'8 cv',
        nbr_personne:'5 personnes',
        nbr_portes:'5 portes',
        airbags:'oui',
     }
     var data4={
       marque:"Renault Symbole",
        photo:"assets/eznault.jpg",
        categorie:'citadine',
        energie:'essence',
        carburant:'8 cv',
        nbr_personne:'5 personnes',
        nbr_portes:'5 portes',
        airbags:'oui',
     }
     var data5={
       marque:"ford fiesta",
        photo:"assets/ford.png",
        categorie:'citadine',
        energie:'diesel',
        carburant:'8 cv',
        nbr_personne:'5 personnes',
        nbr_portes:'5 portes',
        airbags:'4 airbags',
     }
     var data6={
       marque:"Dacia logan",
        photo:"assets/dacia.jpg",
        categorie:'citadine',
        energie:'diesel',
        carburant:'8 cv',
        nbr_personne:'5 personnes',
        nbr_portes:'5 portes',
        airbags:'4 airbags',
     }
     var data7={
       marque:"Hyundai ix10",
        photo:"assets/hyundai-i10.png",
        categorie:'citadine',
        energie:'diesel',
        carburant:'8 cv',
        nbr_personne:'5 personnes',
        nbr_portes:'5 portes',
        airbags:'oui',
     }
     var data8={
       marque:"Nissan Patrol",
        photo:"assets/pajero.png",
        categorie:'citadine',
        energie:'diesel',
        carburant:'8 cv',
        nbr_personne:'5 personnes',
        nbr_portes:'5 portes',
        airbags:'4 airbags',
     }
     var data9={
       marque:"Mitsubishi Pajero",
        photo:"assets/mits.jpg",
        categorie:'citadine',
        energie:'diesel',
        carburant:'8 cv',
        nbr_personne:'5 personnes',
        nbr_portes:'5 portes',
        airbags:'oui',
     }

   this.cardetails.set(data1);
   accent.set(data2);
   peugeot.set(data3);
   renault.set(data4);
   ford.set(data5);
   dacia.set(data6);
   i10.set(data7);
   nissan.set(data8);
   Mitsubishi.set(data9);

  }

voirToyota(){
  var userRef=this.cardetails;
   return userRef.once('value');

}
  }
```

i had added the cars in realtime Database of firebase.And the problem is that i don't know how to get data of the selected car and to display it in detailPage.
 and i don't know what to write in the button detail that will push the detailPage of the selected item.

in this cars Page,user should choose the car that he want and then he can se details of the car in the detailpage, this method is working but i want to retrieve data from database not just write it there. I already had added the data in database i just need to retrieve the detail of the car selected in detail Page.

`

Comment: by the way i know how to push the other page but  what i want to know is what i should  write in the button so i could disopay data of the seleted item in the other page from the firebase

Comment: What have you tried to do to find out how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a specific programming problem, but we are not here to write code for you. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @DaiBok i have added the code that i'm using rightnow,it's working but i don't thinkthat it's a good method, so i had added the cars in database but i don't know how to retrieve details of car that the user selected